# Ambiguous column name error when Scaffold-DbContext EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#reverse-engineer-your-model) to generate EF Core Db context into my project with Northwind database.

I run bellow command for that

```
Scaffold-DbContext "database=NorthWind;server=localhost;user=sa;password=$pass$4;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DbContext
```

But its through an error

> **Ambiguous column name 'name'.**

Can any one tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: Check in dB that which table has column named as name?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in EF core to me, but without the entity classes I can't be sure.

Comment: Probably a view with duplicate column names.

Comment: I check the Northwind Database ,but not found any column with column name "Name"

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103149/ambiguous-column-name-name-error-when-scaffolding-dbcontext