# Ambiguous column name 'name' error when scaffolding dbcontext

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to scaffold from an existing database but the database has multiple tables with multiple schemas and some tables have the same names but within different schemas and i "think" this is the source of my problem and I was wondering if you've faced a similar scenario?

For example `mySchema1.contacts` and `mySchema2.contacts` in the same database.

Here is my command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=table;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --schema mySchema1, -t contacts -o Models
```

Here is my error:

> Error Number:209,State:1,Class:16 Ambiguous column name 'name'.

Comment: EF Core supports SqlServer 2008 and above only. i.e. Databases which has compatibility level at least 100. So connecting to database with compat level 90 on SqlServer 2014 instance wouldn't work.
While this change would make scaffolding Db scenario work, the EF Core will still fail at runtime because the SQL we generate from runtime may not adhere to what is supported on older version of SqlServer.
Are you planning to use the same database with EF? Or you are just trying to use scaffolding tool? Can you give us more details on how you plan to use EF Core with your database?

Comment: Use a connection string with Server authentication instead of integrated security.

Comment: Afshin, thanks but this approach did not work. I received the same error

Comment: Vivek, I'm not sure I understand your question. I am planning to use the same database and I'm also not using sqlServer 2014.

Comment: @RonaldJohnson - Your database compatibility level is not supported by EF Core. Hence you are getting the error. Upgrade your database to at least be compatible to SqlServer 2008.